# Is there an open source offline translating tool

Tags: api, translation, offline

I am searching for an offline, open source translator/API. The translation must not be good, just good enough for analyzing key-words.

I am writing a firefox plug-in. The plug-in computes the likelihood, that a website is trash. It works like a spamfilter, by counting 'evil' words. It works for English, but I am a German and the German language is more difficult for a computer. My idea is to 'simplify' the language by translating it into English and analyze the English text. There was the Google Translate API, but now you have to pay for it. I know that there are other programs to translate websites:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6151668/alternative-to-google-translate-api

They all have one problem. You send the html-code of a website to a server, the server translate the text for you and sends it back. This increases traffic and slows down. The owner of the server also won't like you.

Thats why I am searching for an offline, open source translator. The translation must not be good, just good enough for analyzing key-words. Just using a dictionary and translating word by word won't work.

Example: 'Ich bringe Dich um' means 'I kill you'. If you translate it word by word, you'll get: 'I bring you around.' This translation sounds  weird, but not evil. The problem is that 'bringe ... um' is just one word.

I want to avoid German because of nasty problems like this (and there are much more problems:  23 different rules for plural etc.). I think the programmer who invented automatic translation already faced and solved these problems.

Comment: I work in the translation business. Automatic translation is a very complicated task. I don't know of any reasonable offline translation engine that you could build into your code.

Answer (score 2):

Apache Joshua (Incubating) Home may be the solution for you.

Just have to download the language pack you want, and run it as a server. As they say:

> A key feature is that there are no dependencies (apart from Java 8).
>   Getting a machine translation system running on your own machine is as
>   easy as downloading the tarball, unpacking it, and running the
>   included shell script.

All you have to do next, is to make a web query for obtaining translations (`localhost:5674/translate?meta=list_weights&q=cifra+inferior+a+lo+que+predec%C3%ADan+las+encuestas+%2C+que+pronosticaban+de+mas+del+60+%25+de+participaci%C3%B3n+electoral+.&q=yo+quiero+taco+bell`), and you will obtain the response with the translated text as a JSON.